# How to insert breakpoint at every line which contains a certain word in visual studio 2013 ultimate edition

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I want to insert breakpoint at every line which contains a certain keyword in the whole code.
First i go to edit->find and replace->find in files and found all the references of a keyword in the find result 1 window.
The find result 1 window contains the file paths and the line numbers which contains a certain keyword.

I want to insert the breakpoint at every location returned by this find result 1 window .

Answer (score 2):

F8, F9, F8, F9, F8, F9 (repeat as necessary).

F8 = move to next found result
F9 = Set breakpoint

Comment: find result 1 window contains 6000 lines .its impossible to press f8 f9 6000 times .

Comment: Then get a macro program and have it click F8 F9 that many times.

Comment: what should be the macro and how to add it ?